# Update files at multiple sites at once

Tags: php

I'm looking for a solution to update all of my sites at once.

It's a custom made script and it runs on 1 server.

I frequently update my sites and now I have to upload the files to all those sites and it takes too long.

Is there an easier way to install the new files at all of these sites?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you just looking for an automated deployment tool for your application?

Comment: Yes David thats right :)

Comment: I don't have any specific recommendations, though my preferred deployment tool is a Ruby Rake script.  But a Google search for "PHP site deployment" looks like it has some useful results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux maybe this can help you

http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/

> ClusterSSH controls a number of xterm windows via a single graphical
>   console window to allow commands to be interactively run on multiple
>   servers over an ssh connection.